# Xcode Use 3.2 with newer IOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I have downloaded Xcode 4 but i do not like it much. it also runs quite slow on my machine. i would much rather stick to Xcode 3.2 but is there any way i can use Xcode 3.2 to produce apps for 4.3 and the new ios that is coming and have access to all the new API's and frameworks?

If so, How?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't have an answer, but I do know that the new dev betas come with Xcode 4.3, which hopefully is a BIG improvement over 4.0.3. I like the idea and design, but it needs a bunch of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to produce apps for iOS 4.3 with Xcode 3.2.6 as you can still download this combination from the Apple Developer Program pages.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the newer IOS that come out?

Comment: The fact that you need a Xcode beta > 4.3 to tryout the newer features seems to be an indicator that Apple will not support Xcode < 4 for the coming OS versions.